# How to prevent Google Colab from crashing due to excessive RAM usage while running a loop?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using the Pro Version of Google Colab with 35 GB RAM. Still my session keeps crashing due to excessive RAM usage while running a loop. Unfortunally this loop NEEDS to be runned and i don't see another way to write that piece of code.
Is there a possibility to avoid that? I tried to put a little pause time in every iteration, but the effect is not enough. I also don't understand why the RAM barometer stays high for a long time, even if i stop the loop.

Can someone PLEASE help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit like "Nothing works, what can I do". That is, there are almost no meaningful details except for the fact that you are using Google Colab. I can guess from that that you are probably running python, but not much more. In general, allocated memory doesn't go away when you add pause or after the loop finishes, especially if it's still referenced. It will be eventually reclaimed by garbage collector when it's no longer in use.

Comment: very sorry for that; yeah, you're absolutely right, I'm using Python. I let an object-detection AI detect objects on an image; after that, I use that localization information,  to approximate areas volumina of those objects. for this, i need to use a big loop. 

You mention the garbage collector - can i speed the reclaim up manually? Right now, my only idea is to write iteratively calculated information in a textfile, save it etc. If the session crashes, i can resume from the last saved file

Comment: Hard to say w/o code. In general, don't keep intermediate results if you don't need them. Or don't copy data if you don't have too. Saving results into file is also a viable option. Do the calculations in the loop depend on previous iterations? If not, you are not supposed to see much memory growth.